# lightning:actionOverride and recordtypes

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

I'm using the new Summer17 feature lightning:actionOverride to create a lightning component to override the standard Account Create/Edit. Our accounts have record types so I've left the ability to select the record type in the overridden button.

My question is: How do I access the selected record type in the lightning component?

thanks
Ian

Answer (score 1):

to answer myself.

I couldn't find a way to pass the record type through to the lightning component, so I re-implemented the lightning record type selection dialog.

Not ideal, but it works

ian